# Simple way to position views in a grid

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, layout

I'm creating an app where views are dynamically placed on the screen. I'd like the views to be squares, but I'm wondering if there was some sort of a grid system that will automatically calculate where to place the next item. Here's an example of what my app might look like:

[image]

For example, the 6th square should appear in the bottom right corner.

`UICollectionView` seems really similar to what I want, but if there is a better option, I would love to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

[UICollectionView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html) could take care of that. Here's a [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12) on how to use it.

Based on your edit, I don't think there is a better option, especially if you have many items in your list, or if you'll ever need a custom layout in the future (like [this](http://damir.me/implementing-uicollectionview-layout)). UICollectionView is a very solid grid based display list implementation.